# How to remove toolbar buttons in dankito/RichTextEditor for Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, github-pages, rich-text-editor

I integrated the following library in my Android app project successfully. That works well, Thanks to the author [dankito](https://github.com/dankito) !

[RichTextEditor](https://github.com/dankito/RichTextEditor)

However, I would like to remove some buttons from the toolbar. (Heading 1 - 6, Body Text, Preformatted, Block quot, Insert Checkbox ..)

But I do not understand how to do it. It's written in Kotlin.

Is it possible to do it simply? I am stuck ...

I would also like to change the strings of characters to translate them into French. Is it possible ?

Here is the code of the library that I obviously can not modify.

```
package net.dankito.richtexteditor.android.toolbar

import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import net.dankito.richtexteditor.android.command.*


class AllCommandsEditorToolbar : EditorToolbar {

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) { initToolbar() }
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs) { initToolbar() }
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) { initToolbar() }
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int, defStyleRes: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes) { initToolbar() }



    private fun initToolbar() {
        addCommand(BoldCommand())
        addCommand(ItalicCommand())
        addCommand(UnderlineCommand())
        addCommand(StrikeThroughCommand())
        addCommand(SuperscriptCommand())
        addCommand(SubscriptCommand())
        addCommand(RemoveFormatCommand())

        addCommand(UndoCommand())
        addCommand(RedoCommand())

        addCommand(BlockQuoteCommand())
        addCommand(SetTextFormatCommand())
        addCommand(SetFontNameCommand())
        addCommand(SetFontSizeCommand())
        addCommand(SwitchTextColorOnOffCommand())
        addCommand(SetTextColorCommand())
        addCommand(SwitchTextBackgroundColorOnOffCommand())
        addCommand(SetTextBackgroundColorCommand())

        addCommand(DecreaseIndentCommand())
        addCommand(IncreaseIndentCommand())

        addCommand(AlignLeftCommand())
        addCommand(AlignCenterCommand())
        addCommand(AlignRightCommand())
        addCommand(AlignJustifyCommand())

        addCommand(InsertBulletListCommand())
        addCommand(InsertNumberedListCommand())

        addCommand(InsertLinkCommand())
        addCommand(InsertImageCommand())
        addCommand(InsertCheckboxCommand())

        addSearchView()
    }

}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to modify the library, you'll need to ***remove the dependency*** *of the current library* from the `Build.gradle` and then, adding the library **as a module** in Android Studio.

[**This answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16639227/1065810) already explained how to do that.

About your modification on the library, in `initToolbar` method (or maybe other methods, depends on the library implementation), you'll need to remove the `Button` (or anything you want) plus related codes inside the library.

i.e: Remove : `addCommand(UndoCommand())` to remove `UndoCommand` from the library then look for related codes in the library and remove them too.